# What would the JS Equivalent of this JSON Object from PHP be?

Tags: php, node.js, arrays, json

I'm trying to post this data to an API endpoint I can't figure out the formula it needs to be to actually pass through, I need it to work with NodeJS (axios) for posting

```php
$product = \Shoppy\Models\Product::create([
    'title'         => 'My test product',
    'price'         => 10,
    'unlisted'      => false,
    'type'          => 'service',
    'currency'      => 'EUR',
    'stock_warning' => 0,
    'quantity'      => [
        'min' => 1,
        'max' => 10
    ],
    'email'         => [
        'enabled' => false
    ]
]);
```

**EDITED**:
With @Nick's suggestion (in comments):

```js
       let opts = {
            method: "PUT",
            headers: this.headers,
            data: JSON.stringify({
                "title": "My test product",
                "price": 10,
                "unlisted": false,
                "type": "service",
                "currency": "EUR",
                "stock_warning": 0,
                "quantity": {
                    "min": 1,
                    "max": 10
                },
                "email": {
                    "enabled": false
                }
            }),
            url: `${this.base_url}/v1/products/`
        };

        let res = await axios(opts).catch(function(error) {
            if (error.response) {
                console.log(error.response.data);
                console.log(error.response.status);
                console.log(error.response.headers);
            }
        });
        return res.data;
```

returns

```yaml
{
  message: 'The given data was invalid.',
  errors: {
    title: [ 'The title field is required.' ],
    price: [ 'The price field is required.' ],
    type: [ 'The type field is required.' ],
    'email.enabled': [ 'The email.enabled field is required.' ],
    currency: [ 'The currency field is required.' ]
  }
}
```

Comment: `json_encode($product)`?

Comment: @Nick it needs to NodeJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to wrap the data object with JSON.stringify.

```
const opts = {
  method: 'PUT',
  headers: this.headers,
  data: {
    title: 'My test product',
    price: 10,
    unlisted: false,
    type: 'service',
    currency: 'EUR',
    stock_warning: 0,
    quantity: {
      'min': 1,
      'max': 10,
    },
    email: {
      'enabled': false,
    },
  },
  url: `${this.base_url}/v1/products/`,
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise that :')